# Strategy pattern with return value

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I try create Payment by strategy pattern. But All articles each I read look like this:

```
public interface PayStrategy {
    void pay(BigDecimal paymentAmount);
}
```

But if I need return `Single<RestResponse<PaymentResponse>>`?Is this the right approach?

```
public interface PayStrategy {
    Single<RestResponse<PaymentResponse>> pay(BigDecimal paymentAmount);
}
```

In any real system, the request for payment will return the result

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to implement your problem statement in Generic return type like below:

```
public interface IPayStrategy<T> {
    T Pay();
}

public class PayStrategy1 :IPayStrategy<int> {
    public int Pay() { }
}

public class PayStrategy2 :IPayStrategy<String> {
    public String Pay() { .. }
}


public class Context<T> {
    private IPayStrategy<T> payStrategy;
    public setStrategy(IPayStrategy<T> strategy) { this.payStrategy = strategy; }

    public T doPayment() {
        return payStrategy.Pay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion it's right because it's up to you the definition of the contract, if you agree that all the strategies must return a result that is of type `Single<RestResponse<PaymentResponse>>` for me it's correct